# Spring Integration test with Hibernate failing

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I am using Spring to write integration tests for my Hibernate DAO classes. I am using MySQL for development and H2 as my in-memory database for my integration tests. I import the schema of the MySQL database using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`. Everything works, but my assertions are failing.

The thing is that the DAO class works when I run the application, so I know there is a problem with my test. I think that my problem is that the data is not being inserted when hibernate export the schema. How can I fix this?

Test Class:

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations="/spring/mock-application-config.xml")
public class DAOTest{

@Autowired
private Dao dao;

public VideoDao getDao() 
{
    return dao;
}


public void setDao(Dao dao)
{
    this.dao = dao;
}


@Test
public void findById ()
{
    Video video = dao.findById("someId");
    Assert.assertNotNull(video);
}


@Test
public void findAll ()
{
    List<Video> videos = dao.findAll(1, 10);
    Assert.assertNotNull(videos);
    Assert.assertFalse(videos.isEmpty());//this assertion fails
}
}
```

mock-application-config.xml:

```
<!-- Mock DataSource  -->
<bean id="mockdataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE"/>
</bean>

<!-- Mock Session Factory -->
<bean id="mockSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mockdataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.videovix.model"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">database.sql</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="com.videovix.dao.DaoHibernate"/>
<bean id="videoService" class="com.videovix.util.service.VideoServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mockdataSource"/>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mockSessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

database.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `database` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `videovix`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `artist`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `artist`
--

INSERT INTO `artist` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Miley Cyrus'),
(3, 'Katy Perry'),
(4, 'Imagine Dragons'),
(5, 'Justin Timberlake'),
(6, 'Selena Gomez'),
(7, 'Macklemore & Ryan Lewis'),
(8, 'Naughty Boy'),
(11, 'One Direction'),
(12, 'Bruno Mars'),
(13, 'Rihanna');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `artist_video`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist_video` (
  `Artist_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `videos_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_dd1aa30e7fe34c58832c64e0624` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_4a52607ddfcc468f8749c77412f` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_e1b263d89a864001a33cd027269` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_753c2be39637480281cab765151` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_31df9ea6edd64fe99cb51c05bc5` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_cfdba9990220431c99dd13c0e20` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_4eafcbec6e2a4909adcae83e08e` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_cb784fff2c6148bcb472784d7ec` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_97be99a5fb244a23acefe9a9ab0` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_f82154e4970147c584765636304` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_8c535b222e3c43d48d2b937819b` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_483d1d232e5b47f0966602e31c6` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_8fabe069cc904218a8262efc5ac` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_5764620a13684560884e6346056` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_b9eb1dd5fbd9495b8d1f3b30a62` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_85eda9a560794f9b8ba79bcb719` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ccd42e63f80c4b82ace5ba0001d` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_1c016bc1da37456a8b1648ba48b` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_4d4a065aa23349d9a254ccb5398` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_2821cf2f681444138f8115a21ab` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_5ee099592fcb4782b12ecb111dc` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_126cb73e7f45492a9c8c8ef1e55` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_fa5ad80ec9e44383ae9cd8f2851` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_8b5e303b7c6c431db3a75c0ee10` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_d3be1deeee084b1498d872dfc17` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_beeab2f23ec74f64a2ba3c795d5` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_e5c801f131464ea5a845cc843d4` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_792f7c7d1a2f4883bdb5f53be52` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_47c72ec806c24eb0b66827cb4e7` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ad9a0a0767b34908bd1508c43a0` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_c4812b7dbb5e4d5c8dc3eab95d5` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_e2f40d260c8548a19b9ca6a73a4` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_0a57f3fcf3214fffb778a950158` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_5f4b83ca0f594bf1a31b2b221b1` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_fce00fc5ba744c48802aa273048` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_66764d25ec6d4fc8a44aba34c20` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_4c87e88fd2354e71abd6520e9ff` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_8db7ceddb3424b0aaf7f9cb91a6` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_2ed029fce45a4377b39f40a798a` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_8df810e5daf04b629fa87d8afee` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_5018cb289891442eb31d49b26e5` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_7c64bd676d4e41079d056961cd4` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_7ec6e3f8d3b94948af077851d50` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_6427363762f0481daac740ae1df` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ca3326c1e110449b98b6b847afc` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_21f6914e17bc4e608d1265c9614` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_0569689c2bda4e198e8b66fd333` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_dd1948e41a724e8192cb23aa596` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_e2df5e55539b464cac50f878bc9` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_a905895f8d494ad3ab302a77599` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_a18631136dd74f758f73db0bb0d` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_522f42dd7f264e4aba872ea4c32` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_62de3bb2fdee477392e8f2d6d17` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_1e28c47a58174ce5b00913a405b` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_8d0278620ef340ae837b427aef2` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_22a4be66cd3c4c6183978523c59` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_3fee230efa39416e8a4f72e7e09` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_305a8b23d83f4b6e9c642173bf1` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_3341b3a4d3284de9b553f7fc393` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_3103ebf20d0847cf807630362ea` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_989daef791014e148df37e074e0` (`videos_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_e2b94c38ee6e406e898841ba530` (`videos_id`),
  KEY `FK_066a90f961c34a0ca1083d72fcc` (`videos_id`),
  KEY `FK_a60dbbcdf7914df7a8615e70099` (`Artist_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `artist_video`
--

INSERT INTO `artist_video` (`Artist_id`, `videos_id`) VALUES
(1, 'LrUvu1mlWco'),
(1, 'My2FRPA3Gf8'),
(3, 'CevxZvSJLk8'),
(4, 'mWRsgZuwf_8'),
(5, 'uuZE_IRwLNI'),
(6, 'n-D1EB74Ckg'),
(7, '2zNSgSzhBfM'),
(8, '3O1_3zBUKM8'),
(11, 'o_v9MY_FMcw'),
(12, 'ekzHIouo8Q4'),
(13, 'ehcVomMexkY');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `video`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `artist_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `view_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `defaultImage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `highImage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mediumImage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_1926bd9e86644f088a4fac2a26d` (`artist_id`),
  KEY `FK_247629b656454444bea64dee5f7` (`view_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `video`
--

INSERT INTO `video` (`id`, `image`, `name`, `artist_id`, `view_id`, `genre`, `defaultImage`, `highImage`, `mediumImage`, `viewCount`, `year`) VALUES
('2zNSgSzhBfM', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/2zNSgSzhBfM/mqdefault.jpg', ' Can''t Hold Us Feat Ray Dalton', 7, NULL, 'hip-hop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('3O1_3zBUKM8', 'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/3O1_3zBUKM8/mqdefault.jpg', 'La La La ft. Sam Smith', 8, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('CevxZvSJLk8', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/CevxZvSJLk8/mqdefault.jpg', 'Roar', 3, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('ehcVomMexkY', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/ehcVomMexkY/mqdefault.jpg', 'Pour It Up', 13, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('ekzHIouo8Q4', 'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/ekzHIouo8Q4/mqdefault.jpg', 'When I Was You Man', 12, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('LrUvu1mlWco', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/LrUvu1mlWco/mqdefault.jpg', 'We Can''t Stop', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('mWRsgZuwf_8', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/mWRsgZuwf_8/mqdefault.jpg', 'Demons', 4, NULL, 'rock', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('My2FRPA3Gf8', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/My2FRPA3Gf8/mqdefault.jpg', 'Wrecking Ball', 1, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('n-D1EB74Ckg', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/n-D1EB74Ckg/mqdefault.jpg', 'Come & Get It', 6, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('o_v9MY_FMcw', 'http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/o_v9MY_FMcw/mqdefault.jpg', 'Best Song Ever', 11, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0),
('uuZE_IRwLNI', '//i1.ytimg.com/vi/uuZE_IRwLNI/mqdefault.jpg', 'Mirrors', 5, NULL, 'pop', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `view`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `view` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `genre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewed` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `video_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_74ad9d0cce3d49dcaa0e7b72daa` (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `artist_video`
--
ALTER TABLE `artist_video`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_066a90f961c34a0ca1083d72fcc` FOREIGN KEY (`videos_id`) REFERENCES `video` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_a60dbbcdf7914df7a8615e70099` FOREIGN KEY (`Artist_id`) REFERENCES `artist` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `video`
--
ALTER TABLE `video`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_1926bd9e86644f088a4fac2a26d` FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`) REFERENCES `artist` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_247629b656454444bea64dee5f7` FOREIGN KEY (`view_id`) REFERENCES `view` (`id`);

--
-- Constraints for table `view`
--
ALTER TABLE `view`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_74ad9d0cce3d49dcaa0e7b72daa` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `video` (`id`);
```

Comment: Sorry, read through the question again... deleted previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

This mulit value sql insert statments like

```
INSERT INTO `artist` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Miley Cyrus'),
(3, 'Katy Perry'),
...;
```

are MySQL syntax. Maybe the problem is that H2 does not support them.

Try

```
INSERT INTO `artist` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'Miley Cyrus');
INSERT INTO `artist` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (3, 'Katy Perry');
...
```

instead.